# How to create md5sum for new files

Tags: bash, md5sum

We've created a folder in my dad's computer for everyone in the family to deposit and share their photos and videos.

```
Example of directories:
/Family_Photo/Penguins/2017 09 02/
/Family_Photo/East Beach/2017 10 11/Seaside/
/Family_Photo/East Beach/2017 10 11/Games/
```

Using md5deep, I am able to create a complete list of checksum for all the files in all subdirectories

```
md5deep -r /Family_Photo/ > /Family_Photo/md5sum.log
```

Instead of every time regenerating the complete md5 checksum for all (newly added and existing) files,

How can I create a bash script to automatically detect any files that has not been md5 before and generate the checksum for these new files and append them the original md5sum.log

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: I don't know if md5deep can do that. If not, you could use `find` to filter files based on modification date, then md5 those and somehow patch the main md5 list. If you want to really only append previously non-existant files (and ignore changes), then you'd need to filter based on names in existing list.

Comment: Traversing the directory tree to find the files is the expensive part of the operation; recalculating the checksum for files you already have a checksum for is negligible by comparison, and thus an unnecessary optimization.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to *why* anyone would want to md5 their photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

This should do the trick:

`comm -1 -3 <(grep --text --perl-regex --only-matching '(?<=  ).+' /Family_Photo/md5sum.log | sort)  <(find /Family_Photo -type f | sort) | xargs --delimiter='\n' --no-run-if-empty md5deep | tee -a /Family_Photo/md5sum.log`

**Notes**

- If you use a different path than the one in the example, make sure to use an absolute and canonical path *or* append the option `-exec realpath {} \;` to `find`, because `md5deep` seems to write such paths into the file and we need them to be identical for comparison.
- This command line uses *bash* specific syntax (passing commands as files) and might not work in different shell interpreters.

**Explanation**

- `comm -1 -3`

  - We use this command in this specific case to see which files are new by comparing found files to the existing list.
  - `comm` compares two sorted lists and outputs which lines are unique to each and which are common to both
  - `-1` means: don't show lines unique to first list
  - `-3` means: don't show lines common to both files
  - as a result we only output lines unique to second list
- `<(grep --text --perl-regex --only-matching '(?<=  ).+' /Family_Photo/md5sum.log | sort)` As first file to `comm` we pass a list of the already hashed filenames.

  - `<(...)` is bash syntax to pass the result of a program as file argument
  - With `grep` we extract the file names from the existing file by matching whatever follows double-space
  - `--text` makes sure md5sum.log is always considered a text file and not skipped
  - `--perl-regex` use perl regular expression syntax (we need this for look-behind matching)
  - `--only-matching` only output text that matched the pattern, not the entire line with the match
  - `'(?<=  ).+'` the matching pattern: `(?<=  )` "look-behind" pattern, checks if match was preceded by  (two spaces); followed by `.+` (any characters, one or more)
  - `| sort` we pass the output of `grep` to `sort`, because `comm` expects sorted lists
- `<(find /Family_Photo -type f | sort)` As second file to `comm` we pass all files we find

  - `<(...)` is bash syntax to pass the result of a program as file
  - `find` will recurse a given directory and print out all file names
  - `-type -f` instructs find to only output the names of found files, not directories
  - `| sort` we pass the output of `grep` to `sort`, because `comm` expects sorted lists
- `| xargs --delimiter='\n' --no-run-if-empty md5deep` The resulting list of new files is passed to md5deep

  - `|` connects the output of `comm` to the input of `xargs`
  - `xargs` will call a command (in this case `md5deep`) with whatever comes as input as argument
  - `--delimiter='\n'` specifies a new line as seperator, so that other whitespaces in file names won't get mistaken for a new argument
  - `--no-run-if-empty` we don't want to run `md5deep` if we don't have a single new filename to pass to it.
- `| tee --append /Family_Photo/md5sum.log` The resulting list hashes will be written to the hash file

  - This displays the new files/hashes for your convenience while writing them, if you don't want to see them, just use `>> /Family_Photo/md5sum.log` instead.
  - `|` connects the output of `md5deep` to the input of `tee`
  - `tee` will output its input and also write it to a file
  - `--append` tells `tee` to not overwrite file contents, but to append instead

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the input. After much struggling, I've come up something that meets my current needs.

This part is run for only the first time

```
md5deep -r /Family_Photos/ > /Family_Photo/photos.md5
cd Family_Photos/ & find . -print | sort > today.txt
```

The next part will form my script.
Preparing txt files for every run.

```
cd Family_Photos/ & rm old.txt & mv today.txt old.txt
```

To list all files recursively into today.txt

```
find . -print | sort > today.txt
```

Update the newly added files into new.txt

```
grep -xvFf old.txt today.txt > new.txt
```

Generate md5sum of all new files and append into photos.md5

```
cat new.txt | xargs -d '\n' md5sum >> photos.md5
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll take an ls -l (and store it in a tempfile),
then diff it by a new ls on a Daily? basis, if diff returns 0 all is fine, if diff shows differences.
Then I'll md5 only files reported by diff, update the ls tempfile with the new ls. I'll use the `--LTYPE-line-format=%<` so it won't look for files removed (files present in the tempfile but not in fresh-run ls).

this will be the presudo-code for finding 'new' files:

```
new_files=diff --suppress-common-lines --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' temp_file $(ls -l)

deleted_files=diff --suppress-common-lines --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' temp_file $(ls -l) #so you can log deletions too
```

I leave to write the other code (make first tempfile and hash the data)

Obviously if you have a directory you have to run `ls -R` than run the script from the root of the path you want to keep checkd

Comment: And that's not how you assign the output of a command to a variable (though not using variables would be much better).

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: 1> i wrote pseudo-code (corrections you posted are fine grain) 2> if it's for safety is enough to use ' ' around ls output to tell bash "treat output as a string without interpreting it" 3> i assume that, being a home-use PC no user is intrested in injecting harmful code as filename 3> it's not important 'how' output is displayed, what is important is that it's consistent between different LS executions 4> if you feel it to be necessary replace ls with  for i in *; do; echo "$i";